# Can I hit an API endpoint directly from an SQS message with AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm relatively new to AWS Lambdas, but what I want to do is the following:

When a message lands on SQS, I want some lambda process to hit an endpoint. Can anyone guide me how to accomplish this?

I use node.js if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can hit lambda function through SQS. Below is the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Comment: How can I setup my lambda function to then hit an API endpoint?